# Dynamically fitting images and videos into iframe

Tags: javascript, php, css, iframe

I'm using **Laravel PHP** to retrieve images from a database and display them in a blog application that I am creating.  I decided to use an '**iframe**' tag so that I can retrieve and display both **images** and **videos** in the blog.  The problem I'm having however is CSS related where I'm trying to style the '**iframe**' so that it will adjust its size to different size images and videos and retain their aspect ratio at the same time.

Right now small images are displayed fine but if I use a large sized image, anything with a width greater than 800px, the image will not keep its aspect ratio and/or be clipped.

**View (Laravel PHP Blade File):**

```
<div class="blog_img_container">
  <iframe class="blog_img_container_image" scrolling="no"
      src='{{asset("uploads/photos/" . $funnyblocks_blog->blog_photo_path ) }}' 
      onload='javascript:resizeIframeHeight(this);
      javascript:resizeIframeWidth(this);'  ></iframe><br>
      <p> {{ $funnyblocks_blog->blog_content}} </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.blog_img_container {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:60%;
}

.blog_img_container_image {
    display:block;
    max-width:100%; 
    max-height:400px; 
    margin-top:20px;
    overflow:auto;
}

.blog_img_container iframe {
    border:none; 
}
```

I also tried using some Javascript that I called in the '**onload**' within the '**iframe**' element but its still not producing the desired result.

**Javascript:**

```
function resizeIframeHeight(obj) {
        obj.style.height= obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
   }
   function resizeIframeWidth(obj) {
        obj.style.width= obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + 'px';            
   }
```

I don't really know if this is the correct approach I should use for dynamically retrieving and displaying both images and videos within a single element (In this case the '**iframe**' tag).  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just not use an iFrame ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes it would be easier lol.  So I'm wondering if there's a way I can use a single element to properly display both an image and video.

Comment: And what do you mean by "a single element", as far as I know almost any element could contain an image or video tag ?

Comment: @adeneo By "single element", I originally figured I could just use one 'iframe' tag in the View (Laravel PHP blade file) and use the 'src' attribute to call up either an image or video depending on what's stored in the database.  However, styling the iframe so that it can keep the aspect ratio for both small and large images alike is proving to be difficult.

Comment: Setting the `src` of an iFrame directly to an image or video might work, but it's not a very good idea IMO. I'd much rather add a video or image tag instead, even if it's not just *one* element for both.

Comment: does the iframe have to change size? sounds like a good job for CSS3 property object-fit and a js object-fit polyfill. could possibly combine it with js that resizes the iframe but that's biting off another big chunk with the likely synchronization you'll have to do between that js and the objectfit polyfill.

Comment: @stealthwang I guess for now the iframe doesn't have to change size but if I wanted to change the size depending on the size of the image so that it fits within the iframe, that would be good.

Comment: My answer links two JS libs that when combined will approximate the effect you want (iiuc), though what you're attempting is difficult by nature. Please accept my answer if find a solution using JS libraries as acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a combination of CSS3 object-fit and a JS object-fit polyfill like [**this**](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit) and a JS iFrame resizing utility like [**this**](http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/).

The object-fit property will resize your image to fit/cover the bounds of your iframe (without changing the aspect ratio) when the iframe is constrained by its container and the iframe resize will resize the iframe to be the size of the image when the image is smaller than the bounds of the iframe container.

Integrating these two utilities won't be trivial since they both alter the markup of the page in ways that could influence the outcome of the other plugin. I have done very similar integrations before however and been successful.